# Arbitrary team in moba games.

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine you have a [moba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplayer_online_battle_arena)-game where are N characters and team consists from M players. You have found a team with M players and for a tournament you need to be able to take any combination of M (out of N) different characters and distribute those M characters between your team-members in a way that everyone knows how to play his character.
The question is how many characters in total your team-members have to learn for this?

For example, if M-1 team-members know all character, the last member need to learn only N-M+1 character and your team are good. But this would take M*N-M+1 characters learned in total and most probably you can decrease this number.

If general case is to hard, then what if M=3?

Comment: A character can't be duplicated on a team, correct? (League of Legends works this way for example.) If so, it seems that the best way would be to just take any formation where each character is understood by only one player.

Comment: @lan, no duplicates, correct. Your idea will not work, For example if N=9,M=3 and first player knows how to play chars 1-3, 2nd player - 4-6, 3rd - 7-9, then you can't create a team with characters #1,#2,#3, since 2nd and 3rd players don't know how to play any of them.

Comment: I don't see the problem, why can they only learn characters from too to bottom? Why can't the first player learn only 1,4,7?

Comment: @lan, because if the required combination of characters is #2#3#5 and first player knows only #1#4#7 the first player have no characther to play with.

Comment: Oh, OK, now I see the problem. Alright then, well, you actually can't do all that much better than your example, for a simple reason: if any one player knows fewer than or equal to N-M characters, then one may choose the team to consist of exactly the M characters that he doesn't know, in which case he will have no one to play. This implies the lower bound of $M(N-M+1)=MN-M^2+M$. Even that is only $M^2-M+1$ fewer characters than your example, and I don't think it can work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian pointed out, a lower bound is $M(N - M + 1)$, because if any player does not know $M$ or more characters, then choosing any subset of $M$ of those unknown characters renders that player useless.

This lower bound is in fact tight.  Suppose the characters are imaginatively named with numbers, so the set of characters is $C = \{1, 2, ..., N \}$.

First we handle the case when $N \ge 2(M-1)$.  Consider the subsets $S_i = \{ i, i+1, i+2, ..., i + M - 2 \} \subset C$ (hence each $S_i$ is a set of $M-1$ characters).  Suppose the $i$th player learns all characters except those in $S_i$.  A total of $M(N-M+1)$ characters are thus learnt.

We now show that a team can be formed for any choice of $M$ characters.  Note that this entails matching each character to a player in the team that knows the character.  We do this by appealing to Hall's Marriage Theorem.  Hall's theorem says that such a matching exists if for every subset $T$ of the $M$ characters, there are at least $|T|$ players who know at least one of the characters in $T$.

Equivalently, we need to ensure that any set of $k$ players has at most $M - k$ characters none of them know; that is, for any subset $I$ of the players, $| \cap_{i \in I} S_i | \le M - |I|$.  However, this is readily seen to be true.  For a set $I = \{ i_1 < i_2 < ... < i_k \}$ of $k$ players, the set of characters none of them knows is $\cap_{i \in I} S_i = \{i_k, i_k + 1, ..., i_1 + M - 2 \}$, which has size $M - 1 - (i_k - i_1) \le M - 1 - (k-1) = M - k$, as required.

Thus by Hall's theorem, we can match each of the chosen characters to a different player, and hence form a team.

If $N < 2(M-1)$, then each player learns fewer than half the characters, so it is more convenient to focus on the $N - M + 1$ characters he or she learns.  Let $L_i = \{i,i+1,...,i+N-M\} \subseteq C$ be the characters the $i$th player learns.  One can similarly verify that Hall's condition holds in this set-up as well.

Comment: Well, count me surprised. :) (+1, as it was before the edit, even.)